# Pass Array of Objects in http Post

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

I have a web api developed. I need to pass an array of objects

```
[{"Id":"10010","lati":"12.991845763535506","longi":"77.54596710205078","PSID":"1001"},
 {"Id":"10011","lati":"12.97846402705198","longi":"77.55729675292969","PSID":"1001"},
 {"Id":"10012","lati":"12.967758119178907","longi":"77.54425048828125","PSID":"1001"}]
```

The model class of web api is given below

Locate.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace webapi.Models
{
    public class Locate
    {
       [Key][Required]
       public string Id { get; set; }
       public string lati { get; set; }
       public string longi { get; set; }
       public string PSID { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

and the code corresponding to post method in controller file is given below

LocatesController.cs

```
  // POST: api/Locates
    [ResponseType(typeof(Locate))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostLocate(Locate locate)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Locates.Add(locate);

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
          if (LocateExists(locate.Id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = locate.Id }, locate);
    }

    private bool LocateExists(string id)
    {
        return db.Locates.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
```

I send the http post request in my js script given below

app.js

```
  $scope.adding = function()
  {    
    var idd = $rootScope.vaar;
    var datas = [];
    var len = latitudes.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        datas.push({
            "Id": idd + i.toString(),
            "lati": latitudes[i].toString(),
            "longi": longitudes[i].toString(),
            "PSID": idd
        });
    }
 var jsonData = angular.Json(datas);
  var objectToSerialize = {'object':jsonData};
  var data = $.param(objectToSerialize);
   var config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8'
        }
    }

    $http.post('http://localhost:8080/pool/api/locates/', data,config).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Success");
            }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            alert("An error has occured while adding!"+status);
             });
        }
```

It does not add the above array. Please help me

Comment: Are you getting the correct Json in data

Comment: Change angular.Json(datas) to angular.toJson(datas)

Comment: Your content type should be `application/json`. And your controller is expecting an object but you are passing an array.

Comment: _My latitudes array is not empty. I used angular.toJson(datas). Its not working. The postman also throws error status 400_

Comment: you doesnt need to do `angular.Json()`(It seems angular doesnt have this function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is here:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Locate))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostLocate(Locate locate)
```

and you are posting an array so it should be:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Locate))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostLocate(List<Locate> locates)
```

Comment: The controller is expecting a single item so doing this will still be problematic. It is unclear if OP wants one `Locate` or if maybe `Locate` has a property that is a list of coordinates and doesn't know how to set it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I changed the parameter to `(List<Locate> locates)` and made a logic inside post method. Thank you Glenn Packer